# git push heroku master error, fatal repository

Tags: git, heroku

Got an error when trying to deploy a django web app to heroku using the command

```
    $ git push heroku master
```

Here is the error given after I type that command:

```
    mysite lateefa$ git push heroku master
    remote: !   No such app as vast-spire-40247.
    fatal: repository 'https://git.heroku.com/vast-spire-40247.git/' not found
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Comment: what is the output of `git remote -v` ?

Comment: `origin https://github.com/heyylateef/personal-site.git (fetch)`
    `origin https://github.com/heyylateef/personal-site.git (push)`, which is correct

Comment: see my answer to add the remote url and then, you should be able to push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the remote url.

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:vast-spire-40247.git
```

Comment: I actually deleted the app named vast-spire-40247 on the heroku dashboard, I'm trying to deploy my project on another app I just made, which has a different name. I did that command replacing the name of old app with the new one but I got the following: `lateefa$ git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:latadetona.git
fatal: remote heroku already exists.`

Comment: @heyylateef probably because it does exist. Is latadetona your new app name ?

Comment: you have to delete the actual heroku repository or rename it with git remote set-url heroku git@heroku.com:latadetona.git